# Здесь реально проверить своё стихотворение на знаки препинания?

Tags: поддержка

Очень нужно проверить стихи, помогите, прошу!

Comment: Если очень нужно, пишите.

Answer (score 1):

Да, создайте для каждого стихотворения отдельный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Не забудьте, когда вам дадут хороший ответ, отметить его галочкой!

Answer (score 0):

Можно! Пишите. Если не срочно, конечно.